# Learning asp.net mvc from scratch and hold a real job is it possible in a short time?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hi all
I am a c# developer who has done most of the time windows forms-wcf  and a bit of wpf and in a TDD enviroment.

I really want to switch to web and learn asp.net mvc.

I dont know much about css jquery and html.I guess I have to learn those especially html/jquery.Css just a bit to get me going as I am not a web designer.

I want to be able to hold a job in asp.net mvc.

**Realistically how big is the learning curve before I can hold a job in asp.net mvc?**

**How long is going to take me studying after work 4 hours a day?**

**Do I need to know asp.net in the real world when I look for a asp.net mvc job?**

Just trying to work out if I can really do it.

for my experience in programming 10 years.Many people learn on the job and their acquired knowledge is just enough to keep them going they are no gurus or experts,as family life etc... takes over.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: I think this question can go to programmers.stackexchange.com . Can someone move it or atleast it needs to tbe community wiki

Comment: If you have been programming for that length of time I am sure it won't take you too long to get up to speed.  It takes a bit of time to get your head around the fact that you are working in a disconnected environment.  HTML and JQuery are pretty easy to learn.  Asp.Net MVC takes a little longer.

Comment: @Subhash sorry I didnt know about programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Andrew I might be saying something silly here but from a first look there is no codebehind etc.. and separations like in asp.net.You put all together in a page like classic asp. Is this a wrong impression?

Comment: You can write pages like classic ASP, but the codebehind model is there and recommended for all but the most trivial programming.

Comment: @5arx, He is talking about asp.net mvc. The code behind model is only available in for the webforms viewengine and not recommended.

Comment: @Mattias Jakobsson - Apologies. I'm just about to embark on learning MVC myself (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700538/is-there-a-perfect-model-asp-net-website-for-learning-purposes), hence my ignorant answer :-o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is almost entirely subjective, how quickly did you learn your current language/framework? Use that as an indicator for how long it may take to pick up ASP.Net.

**Do I need to know asp.net in the real world when I look for a asp.net mvc job?**

I would say almost certainly, in fact for any web-based job wouldn't it be nice to have real world sites in your portfolio?  Sure you could probably learn the fundamentals in your spare time but you would stand a much greater chance with some evidence of your achievements.

The issue I have faced personally with world wide web development is the number of technologies involved (as you've mentioned), the ever-changing standards, and also the non-existant standards.  The web is free for all and it takes a lot of experience to appreciate whether you are doing something to a good standard or not.

My 0.02p.

Comment: thanks for your time in replying.Yes is very subjective as everybody is different.I am just trying to estimate how hard it can be. For instance I come from WPF and beleive me it's hard to learn it properly and be confident in what you are doing. Yes a need a project I can show.

Answer (score 1):

If you already know how to do template programming in some other language, you'll find that will help a lot. As for me, it takes about 2-3 weeks to tack on another language, and about a month after that for me to feel fully competent in it; results will vary depending on your motivation and the language/framework itself (Python was really fast). With 10 years experience, if you've picked up other languages on your own, you're pretty much on your way already.

Comment: for better or worse asp.net has hundreds of controls .In asp.net mvc. Do you have to reinvent the wheel in a way?Do you have to write yourself etc...?

Comment: Wow, fully competent in less then 2 months, that's impressive :-)  I would say learning asp.net, css, html, javascript/jquery is going to take more than that amount of time, as you simply cannot achieve a full understanding of the various browser quirks, standards etc. without good solid experience, imo.

Comment: Well, all of that is definitely more than just one language. And if you are learning a language that is alien to what you are used to, it can take longer. Me, I think Python went so fast was that I was already working in Perl. Things sort of just snapped together when I found Python.