# Is there a Perfect/Model ASP.Net Website for Learning Purposes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm looking for a 'model' website/application written in ASP.Net that illustrates current best-practices of architecture, design, code etc. that could be used as a blueprint for development?

I'm working in ASP.Net webforms, but would like to get into MVC so examples from both would be very welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Nerd Dinner](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/) might be worth a look for MVC, it comes with a 185 page pdf walkthough of the code with screenshots. I think it was built as an example for the book ASP.NET MVC 1.0.

There's a bit more info on [Scott Guthrie's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/03/10/free-asp-net-mvc-ebook-tutorial.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can have a web site that uses ASP.NET MVC and ASp.NET Webforms at the same time. Google it and you'll find dozens of samples. But if you weant to see an example of how to implement MVC *Pattern** in ASp.NET Webforms projects, take a look at:  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/mvcwebforms.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your response.

I'm really looking for a MS/industry-approved way of writing apps/sites using ASP.Net and ASP.Net MVC2 as separate things. Have had a look at the NerdDinners app and was wondering if there is anything similar.

Comment: You can find some good samples and tutorials on: http://www.asp.net/mvc A good sample which introduces many new MVC specific features is: http://www.asp.net/mvc/samples/mvc-music-store

Answer (score 1):

It is very hard to find full blown best open source asp.net MVC sites. Here's the ones that go beyond beginner concepts.

- [Code Camp Server](http://codecampserver.codeplex.com/)
- [Kona](http://github.com/robconery/Kona)
- [Orchard](http://orchard.codeplex.com)
- [Kobe... where are you?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/architecture/bb194897.aspx)